# Eclipse with MINGW console doesn't print a file body

Tags: c, mingw, eclipse-cdt

i have a problem with eclipse IDE, me and all my project mates use bash shell, but we need to run the program on Eclipse(teacher's IDE).

Running it in bash shell we have no problems but running it  on the eclipse console we have a problem with the following function:

```
void read_file(char* nome_file) {
    FILE* file = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error");
    } else {
        fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
        long len = ftell(file);
        rewind(file);

        char* content = (char*) malloc(len + 1);
        if (content == NULL) {
            printf("Error");
        } else {
            fread(content, len, len, file);
            content[len] = '\0';
            setbuf(stdout, NULL);
            printf("%s\n", content);
        }
        free(content);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

[image: the console output]

but the file that the function is opening is just a .txt with some text into it.

> Some tips on Eclipse IDE, in the shell the program goes witout any problem

Comment: we try to read just the first 30 elements of the stream but nothing, we think that is a problem with the console stdout, but we don't know how to fix it

Comment: The code is not reading the first 30 elements but the whole file. As I wrote, if `len` is `30` you will be reading `30 * 30 = 900` bytes into a buffer size `31`.

Comment: thanks man, the problem was the fread(), but why on Linux works?